# "no next heap size found: 18446744071789822643, offset 0"

Tags: erlang, heap-memory, crash-dumps

I've written a simulator, which is distributed over two hosts. When I launch a few thousand processes, after about 10 minutes and half a million events written, my main Erlang (OTP v22) virtual machine crashes with this message:

`no next heap size found: 18446744071789822643, offset 0`.

It's always that same number - 18446744071789822643.

Because my server is very capable, the crash dump is also huge and I can't view it on my headless server (no WX installed).

Are there any tips on what I can look at?

What would be the first things I can try out to debug this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, see what `memory()` says:

```
> memory().
[{total,18480016},
 {processes,4615512},
 {processes_used,4614480},
 {system,13864504},
 {atom,331273},
 {atom_used,306525},
 {binary,47632},
 {code,5625561},
 {ets,438056}]
```

Check which one is growing - `processes`, `binary`, `ets`?

If it's `processes`, try typing `i().` in the Erlang shell while the processes are running.  You'll see something like:

```
Pid                   Initial Call                          Heap     Reds Msgs
Registered            Current Function                     Stack              
<0.0.0>               otp_ring0:start/2                      233     1263    0
init                  init:loop/1                              2              
<0.1.0>               erts_code_purger:start/0               233       44    0
erts_code_purger      erts_code_purger:wait_for_request        0              
<0.2.0>               erts_literal_area_collector:start      233        9    0
                      erts_literal_area_collector:msg_l        5              
<0.3.0>               erts_dirty_process_signal_handler      233      128    0
                      erts_dirty_process_signal_handler        2              
<0.4.0>               erts_dirty_process_signal_handler      233        9    0
                      erts_dirty_process_signal_handler        2              
<0.5.0>               erts_dirty_process_signal_handler      233        9    0
                      erts_dirty_process_signal_handler        2              
<0.8.0>               erlang:apply/2                        6772   238183    0
erl_prim_loader       erl_prim_loader:loop/3                   5
```

Look for a process with a very big heap, and that's where you'd start looking for a memory leak.

(If you weren't running headless, I'd suggest starting Observer with `observer:start()`, and look at what's happening in the Erlang node.)

Comment: Thanks. That helped! I found that one of my processes' mailbox was blowing up.